# Prevent file upload filling POST array

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

When uploading files with a silly file size I'm getting the following PHP error:

`Warning: POST Content-Length of 9999378 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

Obviously the filesize is larger than the default PHP `memory_limit`, and as I don't want users to be uploading files this large that is fine, however the error that it produces is not fine.

Is there a method of suppressing this error and show my own formatted error later on the page?

Comment: ignoring error like these can be solved with the `@`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=nb&q=file+upload+max+size&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#sclient=psy-ab&hl=no&client=opera&hs=YPm&rls=nb&channel=suggest&q=file+upload+max+size+form&oq=file+upload+max+size+form&aq=f&aqi=q-w1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..33i21.3964.4408.0.4549.5.5.0.0.0.0.143.484.3j2.5.0...0.0.4acJr78QZVA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=81cb583cff692895&biw=1920&bih=933

Comment: Note that it's not memory_limit, it's `post_max_size` and/or `upload_max_filesize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ini_set()`. Replace xx with your needed value.

```
<?php
  ini_set('memory_limit', 'xxM');   
  ini_set('post_max_size', 'xxM');   
  ini_set('upload_max_filesize', 'xxM');   
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, feeling thick now; upload_max_filesize was what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

It pretty clearly states in the CI docs to use the max_size config item to set a limit (in KB). So something like:

```
$config['max_size'] = '100';
...
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Any reason why this wouldn't work?

Also, take care that your `post_max_size` in Apache setting is also ok for the upload.

From here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Hi Nick,
Thanks for your reply, I have that set currently at 2Mb, and file uploads <8Mb get caught by that. However when the file size is above memory_limit the POST array is getting maxing out before the upload library sees the file.